# Is there a template sheet I can use to capture a person's handwriting including common glyph pairs?

Tags: font-design

I'd like to capture someone's handwriting, I can set up a printed sheet with some guides for x-height and descenders, but wondered if there was already some sort of standard template that also has common glyph pairs, punctuation etc. suitable for western typefaces?

Comment: There's a web app called callgraphr. They have templates you can download and print if you want. Then the service creates fonts for you from your filled in template. Try that.  There's a [video tutorial on youtube](https://youtu.be/CdQUxIwqcw4?si=IL7IYWijoeUyKGJH) which shows how.